# Listing Custom Post Post from certain category

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, list

I have Custom Post `note`
Here my category looks like this :

```
Tutorials

--Class 11
----Physics
----Chemistry
----Biology

--Class 12
----Physics
----Chemistry
----Biology
```

-- represent children and ---- represent grand children

I want to list post  which satisfy the category Tutorial has children Class 11 And grand children Chemistry.

I could write up to

```
 <?php
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'note',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms' => array('Chemistry'),
        'field' => 'slug'
        )
    )
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p><?php
    endwhile;
}

wp_reset_query();
?>
```

I don't know how to filter between children chemistry  from class 11 and class 12 :

Is it possible to list as i think ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with [Multiple Taxonomy Handling](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters). Try this code.

```
<?php
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'note',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms'    => array( 'class 11', 'chemistry' ), // Add suitable term slugs here
        'field' => 'slug'
        )
    )
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p><?php
    endwhile;
}

wp_reset_query();
?>
```